# Upper bound for the sums of powers of factors

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Fix $\alpha \in \,]0,1]$. Is it true that for each sufficiently large positive integer $n$, if $n = x_1 \cdots x_j$, for some integers $x_1, \ldots, x_j \geq 2$, with $j \geq 2$, then $$x_1^\alpha + \cdots + x_j^\alpha \leq 2^{\alpha} + (n/2)^\alpha \quad ?$$

I think that the answer is: "Yes", and I have a proof when $\alpha = 1$. However, I do not see how to deal with $\alpha \in \,[0,1]$. Moreover, if the answer is affermative, I also would like to find the least positive integer $n_\alpha$ such that the inequality holds for each $n \geq n_\alpha$.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.